# Add (Sum) two values in odoo using onchange function

Tags: python, sum, odoo

I have two fields. I want to show the sum of these values in the field 'name' which will be 'readonly'.

I tried like this:

```py
@api.onchange('first_name', 'last_name')
def onchange_name(self):
    if self.first_name or self.last_name:
        self.field_name = self.first_name + self.last_name
        
    #self.name = self.first_name + self.last_name

name = fields.Char(string='Name of the Emplyee', readonly=True, )
first_name = fields.Char(string='First Name')
last_name = fields.Char(string='Last Name')
```

But it's giving me error:

> 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bool") to str'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't have set a value for your two fields.
Basically, if the fields.Char is empty, the value is False.

Try it with a str cast:

```
    if self.first_name or self.last_name:
        self.field_name = str(self.first_name) + str(self.last_name)
```

You can also change the "or" operator by "and" to fix it another way.

Regards,

Comment: Now it kinda works! If I type the first and last name, they appear in the field 'Name of the employee', but when i click save, the employee is saved as FALSE. What could be the problem

Comment: And if i remove 'readonly' from the field 'name', then it.s working

Comment: Odoo will probably not save your value if you have 'readonly' on your field.
But i'm glad to know it works

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check the value of the fields

```
@api.onchange('first_name', 'last_name')
def onchange_name(self):
    if self.first_name and self.last_name:
        self.name = str(self.first_name)+''+ str(self.last_name)
    elif self.first_name and not self.last_name:
        self.name = str(self.first_name)
    elif self.last_name and not self.first_name:
        self.name = str(self.last_name)
    else:
        self.name = None
```

And remove readonly from the name field and put readonly in the view(.xml) file. so you don't get a 'FALSE' value in the name field.

in Model file (.py)

```
name = fields.Char(string='Name of the Emplyee', store=True)
```

in view file (.xml)

```
<field name='name' readonly="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to cast with str

`self.field_name = str(self.first_name)+ str(self.last_name)`

But this won't same the value on database, you will need to add `store=True` to your field, it will be like this :

`name = fields.Char(string='Name of the Emplyee', readonly=True, Store=True)`